# JavaScript Promise Method not returning any data

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am creating a react native application.

I have a back button that fires the function findItem. findItem the uses async method searchJson. searchJson searches recursive json to find parent object based on id. However it never returns any results.

findItem:

```
 findItem() {
    //Pass null so top level json will be pulled
    let result = this.searchJson(null).done();

    let abv = 2;

    // this.setState(previousState => {
    //     return {
    //         data: result,
    //         parentID: result.parentid
    //     };
    // });

}
```

searchJson:

```
   async searchJson(object) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        //use object or pull from porp - all data
        let theObject = object == null ? this.props.data : object;

        var result = null;
        if (theObject instanceof Array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < theObject.length; i++) {
                result = this.searchJson(theObject[i]);
                if (result) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            for (var prop in theObject) {
                console.log(prop + ': ' + theObject[prop]);
                if (prop == 'id') {
                    if (theObject[prop] == this.state.parentID) {
                        return theObject;
                    }
                }
                if (theObject[prop] instanceof Object || theObject[prop] instanceof Array) {
                    result = this.searchJson(theObject[prop]);
                    if (result) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(result != null)
            resolve(result);

    });
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to ```await``` an ```async``` function. The question I have, is why are you using async on ```searchJson```? It appears synchronous

Comment: Hi @Wainage Thanks for the reply. I did try to add the await keyword. But seems like react native did not wanna allow this. I rebuild this whole method and managed to get it working. I will post my solution later. Turns out no need for async or await.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I never got this to work but my workaround was this.

I Modified the findItem method:

```
findItem() {

    let FinNode = null;

    for (var node in this.props.data) {
        FinNode = this.searchJson(this.state.parentID, this.props.data, this.props.data[node].book);

        if (FinNode != null) {
            this.setState(previousState => {
                return {
                    data: FinNode[0].book.parentid == "" ? null : FinNode,
                    parentID: FinNode[0].book.parentid
                };
            });
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And then the searchJson:

```
searchJson(id, parentArray, currentNode) {

    if (id == currentNode.id) {
        return parentArray;
    } else {
        var result;
        for (var index in currentNode.books) {
            var node = currentNode.books[index].book;
            if (node.id == id)
                return currentNode.books;
            this.searchJson(id, currentNode.books, node);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This allowed for all my nodes to be searched and the for loop made so that there is no need for async. This does have some drawbacks but seems to work decently without any massive performance issues.

Comment: There are no performance issues. Your function uses no async functions and does not require any form of async. Look into ```run to completion```.

Comment: @Wainage Yes, that is correct.Thanks. I will go read up on the above mentioned. The first searchJson had an issue where it wouldn't return the right result I thought it was because of async issues turn out the method was just buggy and my react native debugging tools wasn't working but once I resolved that I could easily debug and fix it. Shot for the advice.